# Learning the distribution of a phenomenon's occurrence with partial observation

Tags: distributions, estimation, convergence

I recently came across this problem:

There is a phenomenon, which occurs exactly on one of a set of M (finite) places at every time step t= 1,2,... At each time step t, the place of occurrence is drawn (in an iid manner) from an unknown stationary distribution. We would like to learn this distribution. However, at each time step, we can only observe whether the phenomenon happens at K << M places. The question is, can we provide a consistent estimation of the unknown distribution? Additionally, it would be nice if we could provide finite-time convergence rate as well.

I already have a workaround solution, using an idea taken from the estimation of interval censored data. But the problem seems to be quite fundamental to me, and I believe there is a more principled way to solve this problem. Given this, I would like to inquire whether this is a known problem, and if yes, what is the principled solution for it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you "come across" this problem? Is this for a course? Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its wiki.

Comment: No, this is not for a course. I'm working on a research problem, and one subproblem is this question. The reason I'm asking this question here is that before considering my solution (I already have a solution to this, see my post) into a publication, I'm just curious whether this is a known problem.

Comment: btw, what is this [self-study] tag mean? Sorry if my question sounds trivial but this is my first post ever here...

Comment: The problem looks a little like a paraphrase of a homework question. We get a lot of people posting their HW here, hoping someone will do it for them. That's what the `[ss]` tag is for. If this isn't for a course, you needn't worry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Indeed, the problem statement is very simple and it seems to be very basic. That's why I'm quite surprised when I didn't find anything from the literature (but my lit review was rather superficial than deep). That's why I asked here, hoping someone has already come across similar ones.